# How to show a php variable inside html tags?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to send otp via email, **in the Body part** of the email, I'm trying to show a php variable $otp inside $otp tag but it just Shows $otp instead of the value

```
//value of $otp
$ot=rand(100000,999999);
$otp=strval($ot);
```

of the variable. I tried with the below code.

```
    $mail->Body    = 
    '<h2 style="background: #00466a;margin: 0 auto;width: max-content;padding: 0 10px;color: #fff;border-radius: 4px;">$otp</h2>
    ';
```

but this only returns $otp in mail and not it's value

Comment: And with this code...? `$mail->Body = '<h2 style="background: #00466a;margin: 0 auto;width: max-content;padding: 0 10px;color: #fff;border-radius: 4px;">'.$otp.'</h2>';`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: You enclose your string with double quotes (`"`). And you escape literal double quotes inside the string with a backslash (`\"`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display a php variable in your string you need to close the string with `'` and then use a `.` after the dot you can write php.

In your case you use the single quote so it will look like `'`string`' .` $variable`. '`string`';`

```
$mail->Body = '<h2 style="background: #00466a;margin: 0 auto;width: max-content;padding: 0 10px;color: #fff;border-radius: 4px;">'
    . $otp . '</h2>';
```